# Rename strong params involving a belongs to association id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

When I'm using rails strong params and I need to receive an id of a `belongs_to` association, I normally reference the district model, like this:

```
params.require(:place).permit(:district_id)
```

Then I just send a post request with that field referencing an existing ID of the District model and that does the association:

```
{ "district_id": "1" }
```

Is there a way to change it in such a way that I just pass the district, without using nested attributes, like this?:

```
{ "district": "1" }
```

Comment: Why do you need so? It depends on table. You can add new attribute, name it `district` and it make it as duplicate of `district_id`

Answer (score 0):

`set_primary_key :col_name` in your model will let your change the primary key column name but I really recommend sticking to convention over configuration and rolling with the `_id` paradigm.